# how to solve *** Error in `./key_server': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f361a97b6e8 in c++

Tags: c++

I need help in debugging the below code

server.cpp

```
            void *task1(void *);

            static int connFd;
            static const char *hash_key;




            int main(int argc, char **argv) 
            { 
                int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
                struct sockaddr_in address,clntAdd; 
                int opt = 1; 
                int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
                int getopt_ret=0;
                int long_index=0;
                socklen_t len; 

                string message;
                string salt;
                int iteration_count=10;

                pthread_t threadA[3];




                hash_key=message.c_str();
                if ((hash_key != NULL) && (hash_key[0] == '\0')) {
                    logger("key is empty\n");
                    return -1;
                }

                // Creating socket file descriptor 
                if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
                { 
                    logger("socket failed"); 
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
                } 
                //fcntl(server_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
                 bzero((char*) &address, sizeof(address));
                // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
                //~ if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                                              //~ &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
                //~ { 
                    //~ logger("setsockopt"); 
                    //~ exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
                //~ } 
                address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
                address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
                address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.184"); 
                address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 


                // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
                if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                                             sizeof(address))<0) 
                { 
                    logger("bind failed"); 
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
                } 

                if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
                {
                    logger("listen"); 
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
                } 

                len = sizeof(clntAdd);
                int noThread = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    cout << "Listening" << endl;

                    //this is where client connects. svr will hang in this mode until client conn
                    connFd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntAdd, &len);
                    cout << connFd << endl;
                    if (connFd < 0)
                    {
                        cerr << "Cannot accept connection" << endl;
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Connection successful" << endl;
                    }

                    pthread_create(&threadA[noThread], NULL, task1, NULL); 

                    noThread++;
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    pthread_join(threadA[i], NULL);
                }






            } 


            void *task1 (void *dummyPt)
            {
                cout << "Thread No: " << pthread_self() << endl;
                char test[1024];
                bzero(test, 1024);
                bool loop = false;
                while(!loop)
                {    
                    bzero(test, 1024);


                    read(connFd, test, 1024);

                    string tester (test);
                    cout << tester << endl;
                    //send(connFd , hash_key , strlen(hash_key) , 0 ); 
                    write(connFd,hash_key,strlen(hash_key));
                    if(tester == "exit")
                        break;
                }
                cout << "\nClosing thread and conn" << endl;
                close(connFd);
            }
```

while i run the script it gives the following error.

```
        *** Error in `./key_server': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f361a97b6e8 ***
        ======= Backtrace: =========
        /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x740ef)[0x7f361c1f30ef]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x79646)[0x7f361c1f8646]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7a393)[0x7f361c1f9393]
        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD2Ev+0x3e)[0x7f361cb11b6e]
        ./key_server[0x402583]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f361c19f725]
        ./key_server[0x401dd9]
        ======= Memory map: ========
        00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 261726                             /home/b                                                                                                             g/Encryption/key_server
        00607000-00608000 r--p 00007000 08:02 261726                             /home/b                                                                                                             g/Encryption/key_server
        00608000-00609000 rw-p 00008000 08:02 261726                             /home/b                                                                                                             g/Encryption/key_server
        01b06000-01b38000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
        7f36007d9000-7f36007da000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36007da000-7f3600fda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3600fda000-7f3600fdb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3600fdb000-7f36017db000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36017db000-7f36017dc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36017dc000-7f3601fdc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3601fdc000-7f3601fdd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3601fdd000-7f36027dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36027dd000-7f36027de000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36027de000-7f3602fde000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3602fde000-7f3602fdf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3602fdf000-7f36037df000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36037df000-7f36037e0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36037e0000-7f3603fe0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3603fe0000-7f3603fe1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3603fe1000-7f36047e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36047e1000-7f36047e2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36047e2000-7f3604fe2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3604fe2000-7f3604fe3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3604fe3000-7f36057e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36057e3000-7f36057e4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36057e4000-7f3605fe4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3605fe4000-7f3605fe5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3605fe5000-7f36067e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36067e5000-7f36067e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36067e6000-7f3606fe6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3606fe6000-7f3606fe7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3606fe7000-7f36077e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36077e7000-7f36077e8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36077e8000-7f3607fe8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3607fe8000-7f3607fe9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3607fe9000-7f36087e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36087e9000-7f36087ea000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36087ea000-7f3608fea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3608fea000-7f3608feb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3608feb000-7f36097eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36097eb000-7f36097ec000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36097ec000-7f3609fec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3609fec000-7f3609fed000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3609fed000-7f360a7ed000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360a7ed000-7f360a7ee000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360a7ee000-7f360afee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360afee000-7f360afef000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360afef000-7f360b7ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360b7ef000-7f360b7f0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360b7f0000-7f360bff0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360bff0000-7f360bff1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360bff1000-7f360c7f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360c7f1000-7f360c7f2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360c7f2000-7f360cff2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360cff2000-7f360cff3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360cff3000-7f360d7f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360d7f3000-7f360d7f4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360d7f4000-7f360dff4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360dff4000-7f360dff5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360dff5000-7f360e7f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360e7f5000-7f360e7f6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360e7f6000-7f360eff6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360eff6000-7f360eff7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360eff7000-7f360f7f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360f7f7000-7f360f7f8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360f7f8000-7f360fff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360fff8000-7f360fff9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f360fff9000-7f36107f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36107f9000-7f36107fa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36107fa000-7f3610ffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3610ffa000-7f3610ffb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3610ffb000-7f36117fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36117fb000-7f36117fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36117fc000-7f3611ffc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3611ffc000-7f3611ffd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3611ffd000-7f36127fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36127fd000-7f36127fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36127fe000-7f3612ffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3612ffe000-7f3612fff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3612fff000-7f36137ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f36137ff000-7f3613800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3613800000-7f3614000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3614000000-7f3614021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3614021000-7f3618000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3618177000-7f3618178000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3618178000-7f3618978000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3618978000-7f3618979000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3618979000-7f3619179000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f3619179000-7f361917a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361917a000-7f361997a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361997a000-7f361997b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361997b000-7f361a17b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361a17b000-7f361a17c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361a17c000-7f361a97c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361a97c000-7f361a97d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361a97d000-7f361b17d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361b17d000-7f361b17e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361b17e000-7f361b97e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361b97e000-7f361b97f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361b97f000-7f361c17f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361c17f000-7f361c31a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 260631                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libc-2.22.so
        7f361c31a000-7f361c51a000 ---p 0019b000 08:02 260631                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libc-2.22.so
        7f361c51a000-7f361c51e000 r--p 0019b000 08:02 260631                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libc-2.22.so
        7f361c51e000-7f361c520000 rw-p 0019f000 08:02 260631                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libc-2.22.so
        7f361c520000-7f361c524000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361c524000-7f361c53b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 261723                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libgcc_s.so.1
        7f361c53b000-7f361c73a000 ---p 00017000 08:02 261723                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libgcc_s.so.1
        7f361c73a000-7f361c73b000 r--p 00016000 08:02 261723                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libgcc_s.so.1
        7f361c73b000-7f361c73c000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 261723                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libgcc_s.so.1
        7f361c73c000-7f361c837000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 260639                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libm-2.22.so
        7f361c837000-7f361ca37000 ---p 000fb000 08:02 260639                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libm-2.22.so
        7f361ca37000-7f361ca38000 r--p 000fb000 08:02 260639                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libm-2.22.so
        7f361ca38000-7f361ca39000 rw-p 000fc000 08:02 260639                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libm-2.22.so
        7f361ca39000-7f361cbb4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 652006                     /usr/li                                                                                                             b64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
        7f361cbb4000-7f361cdb4000 ---p 0017b000 08:02 652006                     /usr/li                                                                                                             b64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
        7f361cdb4000-7f361cdbe000 r--p 0017b000 08:02 652006                     /usr/li                                                                                                             b64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
        7f361cdbe000-7f361cdc0000 rw-p 00185000 08:02 652006                     /usr/li                                                                                                             b64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
        7f361cdc0000-7f361cdc3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361cdc3000-7f361cddb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 260659                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libpthread-2.22.so
        7f361cddb000-7f361cfda000 ---p 00018000 08:02 260659                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libpthread-2.22.so
        7f361cfda000-7f361cfdb000 r--p 00017000 08:02 260659                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libpthread-2.22.so
        7f361cfdb000-7f361cfdc000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 260659                     /lib64/                                                                                                             libpthread-2.22.so
        7f361cfdc000-7f361cfe0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361cfe0000-7f361d001000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 260609                     /lib64/                                                                                                             ld-2.22.so
        7f361d1ec000-7f361d1f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361d200000-7f361d201000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7f361d201000-7f361d202000 r--p 00021000 08:02 260609                     /lib64/                                                                                                             ld-2.22.so
        7f361d202000-7f361d203000 rw-p 00022000 08:02 260609                     /lib64/                                                                                                             ld-2.22.so
        7f361d203000-7f361d204000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
        7ffdd756f000-7ffdd7590000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
        7ffdd75bf000-7ffdd75c2000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
        7ffdd75c2000-7ffdd75c4000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
        ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsysca                                                                                                             ll]
        Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you compile and link your code with debug symbols please (probably `-g`) so that you'll get a line number in the back trace rather than just "./key_server[0x402583]"

Comment: One obvious problem is that all of your threads potentially call `close(connFd)` but `connFd` is a global variable.  That could easily result in multiple `free`s on the same pointer.

Comment: @G.M. How could i overcome this problem?

Comment: You *could* easily arrange for each thread to have its own `connFd` variable but that would only solve *that* problem.  You should do as @Rup suggests -- compile with debug symbols and then analyse your code under a debugger.

Comment: "_I need help in debugging the below code_" - You should then make it possible to compile your code by creating a [mcve]. Are you using C++11 or later? If so, use `std::thread` instead of `pthread`.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually one of two things: Your pointer is getting corrupted or you are freeing it twice.

Since you are using glibc I assume it's Linux. If not this probably still helps.

Install valgrind and run your program using

```
valgrind your-binary
```

Valgrind will track memory allocations and freeing and even if memory is initialized before use and give you a much better error. If that isn't enough to spot your bug there are many options to add more tests that you can read about in the manpage.